# Get Highest Version Number in a Folder

Tags: c#

How do I get the highest number file inside a folder `N.2.4.0.12`? The file names are

```
N.2.1.0,
N.2.1.1,
N.2.1.2, 
N.2.4.0.8, 
N.2.4.0.9, 
N.2.4.0.10, 
N.2.4.0.11, 
N.2.4.0.12, 
files.txt
```

I tried so many ways but it is still showing `N.2.4.0.09` instead of `N.2.4.0.12`

```
var FileInOrdered = allFiles.OrderBy(f => f.Name).Last();
```

Comment: Best way to go is to split the version number into separate values and then compare each value. This can be done by using string.Split().

Comment: What values are present in `allFiles` and `Name`

Comment: @Kei he takers the last element after ordering. the problem is that it is a string comparison

Comment: @MongZhu ah yes, sorry I missed that

Comment: @MongZhu can you show me the way?

Comment: @Stefan can u show me the String.Split() way to do it?

Comment: You shouldn't edit your question to remove all information from it. Nor should you post the same question [a second time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57984142/read-the-highest-number-of-folder?noredirect=1). If the answers provided already don't satisfy your requirement, you should edit your question to explain why and give examples of the failure cases.

Comment: If you have N.2.4e10 and N.2.4f10, which is higher? How is E.2.4.0.ee sorted compared to N.2.4e10? Is it hexadecimal?

Comment: @John i changed the questions to look even more clearer

Comment: So is it E.2.4.0.ee or is it N.2.4.0.8? If you have letters (beyond just the first static E) in your filename then that wil change how sorting needs to be implemented. If you genuinely have such letters, then you will not get the answer you seek from your question as it stands.

Comment: @John  how do I get the highest version number if there is a files.txt in my folder?

Comment: Use similar to the answers below but with `Version.TryParse`. Not that it will work if your versions have letters in the middle of them.

Comment: @John ``var FileInOrdered = allFiles.OrderBy(f => new Version.TryParse(f.Name.Substring(2))).Last();`` You mean like this?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.version.tryparse?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: it's not working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Version numbers, when sorted in lexicographical order, will not necessarily be in the version order. You should sort it while taking into consideration that they are versions, not just strings.

There is a [`Version`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.version?view=netframework-4.8) class in the framework to represent a version. It is also comparable. You can just convert all your strings to `Version`:

```
var FileInOrdered = allFiles.OrderBy(f => new Version(f.Name.Substring(2))).Last();
```

It appears that one or more of your files do not have a valid file name. You can use this instead:

```
var FileInOrdered = allFiles.OrderBy(f => Version.TryParse(f.Name.Substring(2), out var v) ? v : new Version(0, 0)).Last();
```

Comment: it' s stated Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: Do your file names all have the same format of V.X.X.X.X? @charles

Comment: there are some V.X.X.X

Comment: What error did it produce? When it crashed, can you see which file name caused it to crash? @charles

Comment: Can you use the split method  instead of Version class?

Comment: @Charles Can you do some debugging to find out which file name caused it to crash? After you found it, find out what's wrong with it. If you don't know how to find which file that caused the exception, see the edit.

Comment: thrown exception is not used

Comment: there still the same error. it stated ``input string was not in a correct format``

Comment: @Charles Edited.

Comment: What is the meaning of ``out var v) ? v`` ?

Comment: @Charles See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-parameter-modifier

Answer (score 0):

Create a method that extracts the version number from the filename and then do the comparison.

```
Version GetVersion(string filename)
{
    var versionString = filename.Substring(filename.IndexOf("V") + 1);
    return new Version(versionString);
}
```

Then use this method like this:

```
var orderedList = allFiles.OrderBy(f => GetVersion(f.Name));
```

Comment: not working. I need to keep ```allFiles``` and ```f => f.Name```

Comment: You still can. By using this method like this: allFiles.OrderBy(f => GetVersion(f.Name));

Comment: I edited my example. You should make sure that the filename of each file consists of a version number in the format "Vx.x" or "Vx.x.x" or "Vx.x.x.x" for it to create a Version object. Also you should check if there is an extension in the filename that should be stripped (by using the File class).

Comment: Well, the contructor of the Version class will do a string.Split() for you. So might be worth while to see why it is not working. Good luck!

Comment: var stringParts = string.Split(".", f.Name)

Comment: Like I said before, I think using the Version class is a better option and you should put effort in debugging this approach. String.Split() is a plan B, but will most likely give you the same struggle you have now with the Version class.

Comment: the verison class show input string was not in a correct format

Comment: There is your problem. Fix that and you will have a working solution. Good luk!